# C language, providing function pointer to a class and have the class operate a function above main()

Tags: c, function, function-pointers

in C++ it's possible to pass a pointer from a function (above main() tree) to a class and have the class operate the function, the keyword "using" is used.

```
class Animation
{
public:
using FunctionPtr = void (*)(int x, int y, const Surface& s);

FunctionPtr DrawPointer;
...
..
.
}
```

in that same class, i can operate the function lower down in the three, above "main()".

```
void Animation::Draw(const Vei2 &pos) const{
    
    RectI temp = frames[iCurrentFrame];

    assert(DrawPointer == nullptr);
    //assert(DrawPointer == nullptr && "no pointer for drawing");
    if (DrawPointer2!= nullptr)
    {
        DrawPointer2(pos.x,pos.y,frames[iCurrentFrame], screensize, sprite); // function above main();
    }
    else{
        //assert(std::cout << "no pointer for drawing.\n" );
    }
}
```

can that be done also in C?

Comment: yes? it works the same except you can't use C++ features like classes

Comment: Not sure what "above main" is supposed to mean.

Comment: @Joshua, the main tree or top level, however you might call it.

Comment: @user253751 i wanna program a PIC32MX Fubarino, i would like to have reusable code for the "digital" input pins, but not maintain a multitude of the same code or have multiple copies of the same code in the code for buttons and other MCU's peripheral.
What can i do?

Comment: that sounds like a completely different question

Comment: @user253751 than i'll make this.

Comment: @user253751 i have cooked a new question

Answer (score 0):

In C you can create a typedef for a function pointer:

```
typedef void (*foo_type)(int);
```

And if you have a function which matches that type:

```
void foo(int x)
{
    printf("x=%d\n", x);
}
```

You can assign a pointer to that function to a variable of that type and call it through the function pointer:

```
foo_type f = foo;
f(5);
```

Or pass it to another function that could use it:

```
void bar(foo_type f, int arg)
{
    f(arg);
}
```

Comment: i wanna assign a address of a MCU's peripheral to a class, but the class has to be able to talk with a function above the main loop. will check your answer tommorow, if that works.

Comment: How do i make a function in a header file in an Arduino project point to a function above the "void main()" loop, i can't use serial.println("..."); from a function defined in a header file. i made a function in the header file that accepts a char array and returns this.